# Why don't ADVs work for Qt Quick apps

Tags: android, qt, qml, qt-quick, android-virtual-device

I have two apps. One is written by myself (a calculator) and the other is [this one](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/qtcreator-transitions-example.html).

I created two AVDs. The first one with the following specs:

[image]

and the other with these specs:

[image]

I tested both of them exactly after creating and also on the Android section of Qt Creator and also both worked well for my "first app". But the problem is that they don't work for the Qt Quick app, while it's more needed! (Because Qt Quick app are more run on mobile devices)

Now the problem: when I run the Qt Quick app using any of those AVDs, they only show a white screen and whatever I do it doesn't show anything else!

[image]

Have you ever tested Qt Quick apps on AVDs please?
What do you think of this problem? I think it's not uncommon.

OS: windows 7 x64
Qt Creator: 5.8
Android Studio: 2.2.3

Comment: Once I've used emulator to test QML application and that worked without problem. But very slowly. May be you have to increase memory usage or set on some graphics acceleration? Also you need to consider that QML works with OpenGL and so emulator should support it.

Comment: I, too, think that OpenGL is disabled. How to enable it? It's very likely that it solves the problem.

Comment: I inscread RAM to 2500 and modified the *config.ini* file to *ramSize:2500MB*. But no changes. I'm going to download OpenGL for my Geforce GTX 750 Ti video card.

Comment: You probably hit [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44697) whose patch is to be included in 5.6.3 or 5.8.1, as stated in the bug report itself. Since 5.8.1 is probably not going to happen you should wait for 5.9 OR cherry pick the patch yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I think you meant I go to [this site](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/61798/1) but it's not clear for me to solve the issue using it.

Comment: Sorry. What I was trying to say is that the patch is available in the commit you have found. That commit should be [cherry-picked](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) into a copy of Qt source and then compiled to obtain a working android kit without the issue at hand. [Here](https://appbus.wordpress.com/2017/02/28/patch-qt-5-8-0-for-qtbug-59026/)    an example of cherry picking whereas [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html) is the guide to build Qt for Windows. FWIW I don't think it's worth the effort for such a minor bug.

Comment: First of everything thanks dear. Let me be frank, I haven't read links still because I want to ask you this question: if you think it's not worth the much effort needed, what to do so? I'm very new on Qt Quick and since I don't have a read Android device, I "have to" use emulators. What other good solution do you recommend me please? I want to create apps using Qt Creator and you now know the restrictions. :( My last ask: I've been suggested to read [this book](https://qmlbook.github.io/index.html) for starting for my purpose, do you agree or you recommend me another good book for starting?

Comment: I do not recommend it IF you have a real device. If you don't...well, that's the only way to go! On mac/linux, compilation is easier since most of the tools are already there (e.g. git) whereas on win it is way more tedious because you have to install/setupt everything. I've personally done a few times and it went well, though, so follow the guides I gave you and you should be good to go! :) As for the book, that's THE BEST book out there right now. Simple, complete, well-written. A masterpiece.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137176/discussion-between-franky-and-bacarozzo).